# Index was outside the bounds of the array - Dynamically Generated Rows

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I don't know why I am getting this error:

c#:

```
 public ActionResult Products(int? id)
    {

        if (id == null)
        {




        }
        else
        {
              var x = _repository.GetProduct(id);
            foreach (var s in x)
            {
                model.ProductName = s.ProductName;
                model.DepartmentId = s.DepartmentId;
                model.MetaTagKeywords = s.MetaTagKeywords;
                model.MetaTagDescription = s.MetaTagDescription;
                model.Description = s.Description;
                model.SortOrder = s.SortOrder;
                model.Status = s.Status;
                model.ProductId = s.Id;
            }


            model.Image_Count = _repository.Product_Image_Count(id);
            var y = _repository.GetProductImage(id);
            List<string> _Product_ImageLink = new List<string>();
            List<int> _Product_SortOrder = new List<int>();

            for (var i = 0; i < model.Image_Count; ++i)
            {
                foreach (var z in y)
                {
                    _Product_ImageLink.Add(z.Product_ImageLink);
                    _Product_SortOrder.Add(z.Product_SortOrder);
                }

            }

            model.Product_SortOrder = _Product_SortOrder.ToArray();
            model.Product_ImageLink = _Product_ImageLink.ToArray();

        }

        return View(model);
    }

 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Products(ProductModel _model, int? id)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            if (_model.ProductId == 0)
            {

                bool _isExist;
                _isExist = _repository.IsProductNameExist(_model.ProductName);

                if (_isExist == false)
                {
                    bool check_product = _repository.InsertProduct(_model.ProductName, _model.DepartmentId, _model.MinQuantity, _model.MetaTagKeywords, _model.MetaTagDescription, _model.Description, _model.SortOrder, _model.Status, _model.ImageLink, 1);
                    int _product_id;

                    _product_id = _repository.GetProductId();

                    bool check_product_attribute;

                    for (int i = 0; i <= _model.Attribute_Count - 1; i++)
                    {

                        check_product_attribute = _repository.InsertAttribute(_model.AttributeName[i], _product_id, _model.Attribute_SortOrder[i]);
                    }

                    bool check_product_image;

                    for (int i = 0; i < _model.Image_Count; i++)
                    {

                        check_product_image = _repository.InsertImage(_model.Product_ImageLink[i], _product_id, false, _model.Product_SortOrder[i]);
                    }


                    if (check_product)
                    {
                        _Message("Success", "You have modified product!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _Message("Error", "Unable to modify product!");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    _Message("Error", "Product already exist!");
                }
                ModelState.Clear();

            }
            else
            {



            }




        }
        else
        {
            _Message("Error", "Please check the form carefully for errors!");

        }


        return View(_model);

    }
```

Html:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Image_Count)
                        <table id="image" class="list">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="left">Image</td>
                                    <td class="right">Sort Order</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            @{

        for (var i = 0; i < Model.Image_Count; i++ )
        {


                                <tbody id="image-row">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="left">
                                            <table>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <img class="img-tag" id="img-row-tag" src="@Model.Product_ImageLink[i]" alt="no-image" />
                                                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Product_ImageLink[i])
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <a id="lnk" onclick="_file_upload(this);" class="button">Upload File</a>
                                                        <input id="file_row" class="file-tag" onchange="readURL_(this, i);" type="file" name="file_row" />
                                                        <div class="validation-area">
                                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Product_ImageLink[i])
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>

                                        </td>
                                        <td class="right">
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Product_SortOrder[i])
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="left"><a onclick="$('#image-row' + i).remove();" class="button">-</a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
        }

                            }
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2"></td>
                                    <td class="left"><a onclick="addimage();" class="button">+</a></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                        </table>
```

Jquery:

```
var attribute_row = 1; function addattribute(){html = '<tbody id="attribute-row' + attribute_row + '">';html += '  <tr>';html += '    <td class="left">@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.AttributeName)<div class="validation-area">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.AttributeName)</div></td>';html += '    <td class="right"><input type="text" name="Attribute_SortOrder" id="Attribute_SortOrder"></td>';html += '    <td class="left"><a onclick="$(\'#attribute-row' + attribute_row + '\').remove();" class="button">-</a></td>';html += '  </tr>';html += '</tbody>';$('#attribute tfoot').before(html);attribute_row++;$('#Attribute_Count').val(attribute_row);}
```

The code returns what has already been stored in the database. When a new row is added and and the update button is clicked it throws up the error.

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < model.Image_Count; ++i)` shouldn't be `for (var i = 0; i < model.Image_Count; i++)` ? Debug your code and see where your code is outside of bound and fix it.

Comment: I have already done that. The error occur on the view loop.